# How to block inline onclick event and call it later in own click listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I block the inline onclick event of a button and call the function defined in that onclick later in my own click listener?

I try to inject some code which should execute before the button's onclick code is getting called.

```js
function doSomething(el) {
  console.log("doSomething was called...");
}

jQuery("#test").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("click listener called...");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test" onclick="doSomething(this)">Submit</button>
```

Comment: So, you are looking to change the precedence?

Comment: I try to execute some code before the onclick code is getting called, so yes, in other words, the precedence should be swapped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a reference to the original inline handler from the element through its `onclick` property, which you can then reset to `null`. Then you can call the original inline function from within your own jQuery event handler when required, something like this:

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
var originalInlineClickHandler = test.onclick;
test.onclick = null;

function doSomething(el) {
  console.log("doSomething was called...");
}

$(function() {
  jQuery("#test").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("click listener called...");
    originalInlineClickHandler();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test" onclick="doSomething(this)">Submit</button>
```

It should be noted that this is rather hacky. I'd strongly suggest removing the inline event handler from the HTML, if possible.

Comment: Does it also work with jQuery btw? I tried `var originalInlineClickHandler = jQuery("#test").onclick;` but it does not work. It says: *Uncaught TypeError: originalInlineClickHandler is not a function*

Comment: Not like that as jQuery doesn't have an `onclick` property. You could use `$('#test')[0].onclick` instead, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an event for hover or mouseDown, but neither of those promise that there will be a click event. If you want to delete the inline onclick completely, you can unset it on the element in one of these events with something like `element.onclick = null;`.

Comment: It does not answer my question sorry

Comment: I agree that it doesn't fully answer the question, but it doesn't give you a way to access the button before it's clicked. How you want to save the value to click that button later is more dependent on your app.  Regardless, I hope the other answer works better for you!